# SQL - Check field value for negative number and change value if negative

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am dealing with monthly hours for project resources and I have a requirement where each resource record cannot have negative hours. (Don't ask)

I am looking to create a stored procedure (SQL Server) to check each month's hours to see if a record has one or more negative values. If the record has one or more negative values, I have to use the remaining monthly values to offset the negative.

Refer to the link: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95519/2)

This example record, for month 3, it has -48 hours. I need to use month 1 and 2, which have 24 hours each, to offset the -48 hours in month 3. So months 1 through 3 would be 0, since the total hours for month 1 and 2 would be +48, which would negate the negative hours for month 3.

Just a note: the negative number could be in any month and the hours to offset the negative number could come from one or multiple months. The goal is to 0-out the negative hours. If there aren't enough hours to offset the negative, then every month's hours would be set to 0.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: In this case I would probably use a CLR-Function and do the heavy lifting in .NET. While you could do do it in a stored procedure, it would require a lot of code, I would probably be using cursors, pivots and case statements, not exactly what SQL queries are best at.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you want or at least gets you close:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR1 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR1 END AS FCST_HR1,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR2 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR2 END AS FCST_HR2,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR3 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR3 END AS FCST_HR3,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR4 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR4 END AS FCST_HR4,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR5 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR5 END AS FCST_HR5,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR6 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR6 END AS FCST_HR6,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR7 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR7 END AS FCST_HR7,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR8 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR8 END AS FCST_HR8,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR9 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR9 END AS FCST_HR9,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR10 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR10 END AS FCST_HR10,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR11 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR11 END AS FCST_HR11,
  CASE WHEN FCST_HR12 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE FCST_HR12 END AS FCST_HR12
FROM 
(select 
  FCST_HR1,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 AS FCST_HR2,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 AS FCST_HR3,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 AS FCST_HR4,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 AS FCST_HR5,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6 AS FCST_HR6,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6
  + FCST_HR7 AS FCST_HR7,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6
  + FCST_HR7 + FCST_HR8 AS FCST_HR8,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6
  + FCST_HR7 + FCST_HR8 + FCST_HR9 AS FCST_HR9,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6
  + FCST_HR7 + FCST_HR8 + FCST_HR9  + FCST_HR10 AS FCST_HR10,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6
  + FCST_HR7 + FCST_HR8 + FCST_HR9 + FCST_HR10 + FCST_HR11 AS FCST_HR11,
  FCST_HR1 + FCST_HR2 + FCST_HR3 + FCST_HR4 + FCST_HR5 + FCST_HR6
  + FCST_HR7 + FCST_HR8 + FCST_HR9 + FCST_HR10 + FCST_HR11 + FCST_HR12 AS FCST_HR12
from RSRC_HR
where rsrc_id = '2045831579F511750') t
```

A little difficult to understand exactly what you want, but it seems like a running total across columns?